# jquery movable map + throw another div

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="menu">
        <div id="leftMenu">...width 250,height 100 position absolute left 0 top 0</div>
        <div id="rightMenu">...width 250,height 100 position absolute right 0 top 0</div>
   </div>
   <div id="movable"></div>
</div>
```

and this jquery

```
$('body').on("mousedown",function(e){....});
$('#movable').on("mousemove",function(e){......});
```

It looks like this image - [image]

what the problem?actually I can start moving only below menu, but I want to start moving between left menu and right menu is it possible?

edit: I have only 1 idea- remove div with id menu

Comment: Do you want drag & drop ? I can't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: yes I have it already, but I can start dragging only below div with id menu, and I want to start dragging inside #menu, but only in white part(between left menu and right menu)

Comment: Why don't you provide an example using http://jsfiddle.net/ and clear up your explanation of the problem. And please color each thing if possible, because all it's `whitespace` on your picture. You can provide another picture if jsfiddle example is hard for you to provide just take your time and explain it well I'll help you out if I understand you right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/262q7/, but I am not sure now because on that example it works..but in my code if I try to move image between colored divs it is not moving

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, problem was width setting position absolute/relative on elements